# How to find the commands executed by a /bin/bash process? (Linux)

Tags: linux, process, monitoring, proc

TL;DR :
I want to get the command running (if running) in the /bin/bash processes.

I want a script that can identify in the /bin/bash process the command /bin/bash is running. Tried to find it in /proc/[pid]/cmdline but it only show /bin/bash.

Is there a way to do this or what I'm wondeing is impossible. :o

I'm asking because when I run a `ps -ef`, some processes (like ssh) show how they'r running.

```
user      30410 30409  0 10:58 pts/0    00:00:00 ssh name@127.0.0.1  <-- here
```

There is the ssh command fully printed.

We can see the same if I do the command `ps -ef | grep "/bin/bash"`, it return :

```
user     20080  4999  0 13:40 pts/9    00:00:00 grep /bin/bash  <-- here
```

There is the command grep /bin/bash printed.

But if I run a bash loop like `while true; do echo "hello"; done`
And then I do `ps -ef | grep "while"` It return nothing !!!

Answer (score 1):

that depends on what type of command are you looking for.

for external commands running from a shell, "ps -efH" shows you a hierarchical list of running processes, which you can then find the info you need.

bash built-in commands doesn't show up on ps list, you will have to enable script debugging using "set -x" and then monitor the stderr to see what the script is doing.

To answer the edits you made:
while is a built-in, so it doesn't show up.  but the "echo" will show up in the "ps -efH" output i mentioned above.

Comment: I want to find a way to monitor the process popping and especially the command running. I want my little inotify bash script to black list some commands and kill them if they are not allowed. 

Is that possible with a inotify watching /proc and triggering a kill if not allowed?

Comment: so you want to find out the run away or rogue script that consume too much cpu...  that's a different problem.

Comment: Yeah, its my final objectives. Will close this if I find a solution or find out I don't need it. Will create a new topic on this subject.

Comment: @redcore. Easiest tool  for finding high CPU processes is `top` (or `htop`) . That gives you the process id and some info about the offending command. There are many techniques to drill down further based on what you find with [h]top. One hint: when you find a high CPU proc, take that pid, and then explore with `/bin/ls -l /proc/$ProblemPIDNum`. Good luck.